# How to show textarea cursor automatically?

Tags: html, textarea, text-cursor

Can you guys tell me how to show textarea cursor automatically? Usually when i click on textarea i have an text cursor. Is there any possibility to show it straightaway?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Set the `autofocus` attribute ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autofocus), [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/attributes-common-to-form-controls.html#autofocusing-a-form-control)) on the control.

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="30" autofocus></textarea>
```

---

It is also possible to set it with JavaScript, but that can interfere with normal use of the page (especially with screen readers which use the focus point to read from) (so can the autofocus attribute, but it is at least standard so screen reader software can be written to work around it).

The JavaScript technique I don't recommend is:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="30" id="mytextarea"></textarea>
<script> document.getElementById('mytextarea').focus(); </script>
```

Note that this **does not** use the onload event. That event doesn't fire until the entire document, including dependencies such as images, is loaded so there is usually a significant delay in which the user might start interacting with the page. Setting the focus after that point is likely to break whatever the user is in the middle of.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the focus. If you dont use any external libraries (like jQuery) try this:

```
<body onload="document.yourForm.yourTextarea.focus();">

<form name="yourForm">
<textarea name="yourTextarea"></textarea>
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: i didn't downvote you, but even though your solution "works", it's a bad solution. in other words, you could effectively sign all your receipts by slashing your finger and signing in blood, but why would you when you can just use a pen?

Comment: Wow, "slashing your finger and signing in blood" ... a little melodramatic for Stack Overflow, don't you think?  There are no "bad" solutions, ever, only "good" or "bad" solutions *for a particular circumstance*.  If your circumstance is that you're not using jQuery, and an `autofocus` attribute isn't cutting it (maybe you need to support IE8) then this answer is a perfectly "good" one.

Answer (score 0):

It is HTMLElement called `focus()` method.

Here's the link with an example: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp

Answer (score -1):

You can give `focus` to that textbox while loading page

Comment: The question is asking **how** to do that.

Answer (score -4):

Use This Code: `<textarea rows="20" cols="100">`

Your HTML Code:
`<textarea>`

Comment: That won't set the focus on it automatically